# Maximal orthonormal set with fixed distance to subspace

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to prove an upper bound on the size of a set $S$ of orthonormal vectors in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ whose elements all have the same distance to the unit sphere of a strict subspace $\mathcal{K}$. I checked a couple of Halmos's books to see if this was something standard, but couldn't find anything.

Specifically, let $\mathcal{H}$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and let $\mathcal{K}$ be a strict subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. Let $S:= \lbrace \eta_{k} \rbrace_{k}\subset \mathcal{H}$ satisfy $$\max_{  \psi \in \mathcal{K}, \Vert \psi\Vert=1}\vert \left( \psi, \eta_{k}\right) \vert^{2} = a$$ where $0<a<1$ for all $k$. Is it true that $$\vert S\vert \le 2\text{min}\lbrace   \text{dim}\mathcal{H}-\text{dim}\mathcal{K} ,\text{dim}\mathcal{K} \rbrace\ ?$$

Motivating example: it seems straightforward to verify this when taking $\mathcal{K}$ to be one- and two-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. I was also keeping in mind the situation $a=1/2$ and $\dim \mathcal{H}\le 2\dim\mathcal{K}$, for which one can construct the set $$\lbrace {e_{1}\pm e_{\dim \mathcal{K}+1}\over \sqrt{2}}, {e_{2}\pm e_{\dim \mathcal{K}+2}\over \sqrt{2}},\ldots ,{e_{\dim\mathcal{K}}\pm e_{\dim{K}+\text{min}\lbrace \dim\mathcal{H}-\dim \mathcal{K},\dim \mathcal{K}\rbrace}\over \sqrt{2}} \rbrace$$

Comment: It is strange to ask whether $|S|<2\min(a,b)$, since that is equivalent to the combination of the two simpler questions $|S|<2a$ and $|S|<2b$.

Comment: Don't the columns of the DFT matrix give an easy counterexample? Just take K to be the span of the first identity basis element.